# Hibernate LocalDateTime: Postgresql schema generation creates columns of type "bytea" in external Tomcat

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, spring-boot

Im having a problem with hibernate schema generation of my postgresql databse for my webapp which is hosted in a external tomcat (8.5.20).
For this i have set the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create-drop` in my spring boot app.
When im running the app inside my eclipse with the embedded tomcat all **LocalDateTime** columns are generated as 
`timestamp without time zone` which is fine.
But when generating the the war file and deploying to a external tomcat with activated schema generation all these columns are generated as type
`bytea`.

I was trying to define global jndi resources (server.xml) linked in context.xml, only context.xml based jndi reosurces and with the spring.data and spring.jpa configuration im having when running in eclipse in my application.properties. But as soon as i deploy the generated war to my external tomcat these columns are generated as bytea.

I also put the postgresql-42.1.1.jar to the tomcat lib folder but also without any success.

These are my settings for my local environemt which work fine:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

This is a example of defining the tomcat jndi datasource in context.xml which generates the bytea columns:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/test" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
    username="postgres" password="postgres" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test">
</Resource>
```

In this case my application properties looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:comp/env/jdbc/test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Last i tried is to build and run a generated jar. Columns are again generated of type 'bytea'. So the only variant where the columns are generated as timezones is running the app inside eclipse...

Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

In general should NOT work. And yes, BLOB convention is used. 
Java8 LocalDateTime isn't officially part of JPA 2.1

Question is WHY one config positive work? I'm almost sure, PostgreSQL has nothing t problem.

Maybe You have newer / older hibernate version? Newer Hibernate versions maybe have 'early release' ? Pure presumption, I'm in latest years Eclipselink user, and Eclipselink does NOT implement.

Generally suggested and good proven way is JPA type converter

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

    @Override
    public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
        return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
        return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
    }
}
```

EDIT: maybe You have such converter in some JAR, so automatically is forced???

EDIT2: maybe better code and theory by Adam Bien?

http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/new_java_8_date_and

Comment: What i just found out: Anotating the LocalDateTime properties in my Entities with @Column(columnDefinition= "timestamp without time zone") works...But still no idea why i _need_ to do this for all environements except my eclipse environment....

Comment: In my opinion every manual 'intrusion' to JPA is not too good, personally do not like 'columnDefinition'.  Creation iin this case is OK, but real operations? Did You checked?

Comment: It is part of JPA 2.2, so if your JPA provider supports that, then ought to be supported "out of the box" actually

Comment: @BillyFrost agree, and wait for long awaited JPA 2.2 (not official yet - 08.2017) and next parts JEE8. Type converter (from JPA 2.0 ???) is very good and tested thing over years with Joda DateTime

Comment: Well what goes in JPA 2.2 is official and approved, and some providers support all or parts of it (DataNucleus does all, EclipseLink does most if not all from what I see, Hibernate latest has java.time types IIRC). `AttributeConverter` is from JPA 2.1 and is a perfectly usable workaround